# How to count words from strings read from a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, file-io

I am trying to create a  program which takes all text file in a given path and save all strings in one list:

```
import os
import collections

vocab = set()
path = 'a\\path\\'

listing = os.listdir(path)
unwanted_chars = ".,-_/()*"
vocab={}
for file in listing:
    #print('Current file : ', file)
    pos_review = open(path+file, "r", encoding ='utf8')
    words = pos_review.read().split()
    #print(type(words))
    vocab.update(words)
pos_review.close()

print(vocab)
pos_dict = dict.fromkeys(vocab,0)
print(pos_dict)
```

**Input**

```
file1.txt: A quick brown fox.
file2.txt: a quick boy ran.
file3.txt: fox ran away.
```

**Output**

```
A : 2
quick : 2
brown : 1
fox : 2
boy : 1
ran : 2
away : 1
```

Until now I am able to make a dictionary of those strings. But now not sure how to make key, value pair of strings and their frequency in all text files combined.

Comment: Parse the dictionary by looping over the key,values `for k, v in dict:`, then just print out the information

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps,

```
import os
import collections

vocab = set()
path = 'a\\path\\'

listing = os.listdir(path)
unwanted_chars = ".,-_/()*"
vocab={}
whole=[]
for file in listing:
    #print('Current file : ', file)
    pos_review = open(path+file, "r", encoding ='utf8')
    words = pos_review.read().split()
    whole.extend(words)
pos_review.close()

print(vocab)

d={} #Creating an Empty dictionary
for item in whole:
    if item in d.keys():
        d[item]+=1 #Update count
    else:
        d[item]=1
print(d)
```

Comment: I am able to create a dictionary with count value for one file but as I am taking all the files in a given directory, it is creating list of the list. For which straight forward method isn't working

Comment: modified the answer. is it the one you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

## Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

- `Counter` is a `dict` subclass for counting iterables

### Data

- Given 3 files, named `t1.txt`, `t2.txt` & `t3.txt`
- Each file contains the following 3 lines of text

```py
file1 txt A quick brown fox.
file2 txt a quick boy ran.
file3 txt fox ran away.
```

### Code:

#### Get the files:

- [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```py
from pathlib import Path

files = list(Path('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files').glob('t*.txt'))
print(files)

# Output
[WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/t1.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/t2.txt'),
 WindowsPath('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/t3.txt')]
```

#### Collect and count the words:

- Create a separate function, `clean_str`, for cleaning each line of text
- [`str.lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) for lowercase letters
- [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) & [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#string.punctuation) for highly optimized punctuation removal

  - From [Best way to strip punctuation from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string)

```py
from collections import Counter
import string

def clean_string(value: str) -> list:
    value = value.lower()
    value = value.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    value = value.split()
    return value

words = Counter()
for file in files:
    with file.open('r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = clean_string(line)
            words.update(line)

print(words)

# Output
Counter({'file1': 3,
         'txt': 9,
         'a': 6,
         'quick': 6,
         'brown': 3,
         'fox': 6,
         'file2': 3,
         'boy': 3,
         'ran': 6,
         'file3': 3,
         'away': 3})
```

#### List of `words`:

```py
list_words = list(words.keys())
print(list_words)

>>> ['file1', 'txt', 'a', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'file2', 'boy', 'ran', 'file3', 'away']
```

Answer (score 0):

this also works

```
import pandas as pd
import glob.glob

files = glob.glob('test*.txt')
txts = []

for f in files:
    with open (f,'r') as t: txt = t.read()
    txts.append(txt)

texts=' '.join(txts)
df = pd.DataFrame({'words':texts.split()})
out = df.words.value_counts().to_dict()
```